# Using grand central dispatch in Linux

Tags: macos, grand-central-dispatch

Is this possible, since Apple has open sourced the code (`libdispatch`?) I'm bit confused as to how one can make use of this. Is this like a library with an API that any application can make use of, or an OS feature built into Mac OS X? Can application built "for" Macs and iPhone (with iOS 4) alone make use of this library?

I assume one has to run a port to make `gcc` also compatible with the new semantic that Apple has introduced.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Having read the [Ars Technica overview](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/09/apple-opens-gcd-challenges-impede-adoption-on-linux.ars), it appears there are several challenges

- GCD makes extensive use of blocks (an Apple extension to C that approximates closures) which means your compiler needs to support blocks.  The standard version of gcc has no support for blocks, so you'll either have to port Apple's changes to the Linux gcc or use clang/llvm.
- The Mac OS X version of GCD involves some code in the kernel.  Clearly, if kernel changes are required to Linux to support GCD, that is a major piece of work. However, it seems that a user space only port is possible.
- GCD is licensed under the Apache License.  Apparently, this license is not compatible with GPL v2.  So you cannot use GCD in any app distributed under GPL v2.  GPL v3 is OK though, so an app licensed under GPL v2 "or later" is OK.

Having said all that, the [FreeBSD port](http://www.macresearch.org/grand-central-dispatch-ported-freebsd) has been done, so it must be possible.

Comment: I would switch to Clang anyway. It's errors are way more convenient. :)

Comment: @Time Machine: I agree.  I have moved over to clang for my Xcode projects already.  Allegedly it compiles quicker and produces better optimised code too, although I have never seen benchmarks to prove it.

Comment: Lower quality ports are always possible. And thats what everything until now unfortuantely is even 11 years after this question. Without kernel support it's just not as useful. Its so sad that we still have no well working thread pool for linux.

Answer (score 14):

It's almost a year later but I'm [using it quite happily](http://chris.mowforth.com/2011/07/31/installing-grand-central-dispatch-on-linux/) on Ubuntu Natty. Proper packages are coming in Oneiric.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up, Chris.

Comment: @bacchus Since Twitter cannibalized Posterous (and my blog!) I haven't had time to get it back up somewhere, thanks for reminding me! I'll let you know when it comes back online.

Comment: @bacchus I finally managed to get my blog up. I updated the link in the answer.

Comment: @hmijail I moved the blog again but haven't migrated the old posts, thanks for reminding me! (Although given that I wrote it 5 years ago, it may not be much use ;)